# "You may not remove the user from their primary group."

Tags: unix, permissions

Once upon a time I created a newuser.

```
sudo adduser newuser --ingroup admin
```

and I didn't want them as an admin any longer

```
sudo deluser newuser admin
```

/usr/sbin/deluser: You may not remove the user from their primary group.

Then the wicked witch of the west came and stopped me from removing them from that group. I tried adding a new group for them, but it didn't seem to matter. Even if they are in two groups, I cannot do this command.

Comment: Try `adduser newuser --ingroup staff` (where `staff` is the new primary group you want the user in) to move them to a different group as their primary group, then try the `deluser`.  I've not tried it...read the `adduser` man page carefully.

Comment: The solution was to change the primary group of the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem.
First I used:

```
usermod -g group user
```

to give the user `user`, his primary group, `group`.
Then I used:

```
deluser user group
```

Comment: Thank you very much. No tutorial I found mentioned this case.